# Removing Object from Array of Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hey Guys I am exporting some data.
And the challenge I am facing is the data should be in Array of Objects but don't know the data format is Array in Array of Objects.
I can write a script to transform the data to the desired format. 
**Can anyone help me out with how can I remove the object from the inner array to the outer array?** 
The data is in this format.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "id": "4101"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**My Resultant Format looks like this**
Can anyone help me write a javascript to accomplish this objective

```
{
  "data": [
      {
        "id": "4104",
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to do any transformation. Just assign `obj.data[0]` to a new variable called `data`, and then use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give a try to this :

```
var a=obj.data.splice(0, 1);
obj.data.push(a[0]);
```

or in one line if you want :

```
obj.data.push(obj.data.splice(0, 1)[0]);
```

Provided you cannot correct the input at the source.

Comment: Thanks, @Fabien, It worked out after a few adjustments in the script as per requirements.